# What's the source and rest of the verse "dhanam mūlam idaṃ jagat" ("money forms root of this world?")

Tags: identification-request, translation-request, sanskrit, shloka

I was watching [a Telugu movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goutham_Nanda) recently and the tagline of the movie was:

> *dhanam mūlam idaṃ jagat*
>
> (money forms root of this world)

After some [digging around][2], it seems this line is only part of a verse (shloka) and it's possible the movie has taken the line out of context...

The full shloka is:

> *Vedamulam Idam braamhyam*
>
> *Krushimulam Idam dhanyam*
>
> *Bharya Mulam idam Gurham*
>
> *Dhanam mulam idam Jagath*

One English translation/explanation is given on [the internet](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Dhanam-Moolam-Idam-Jagath-1) as:

> The Vedas are the base (root cause) for attaining The Divine Knowledge
>
> The wife is the root cause for the house (she is thus the housewife)
>
> Agriculture is the root cause for the paddy
>
> Wealth is the root cause for this world of worldly pleasures

Where is that shloka from? Is the above quoted verse the full and correct verse and to what degree is the translation correct? Also, is this verse proper Hindu scripture or is it a [subhashita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhashita)?

Comment: not sure about sanskrit verse, but there is equivalent tamil Thirukkural 'arul illarku avvulagillai, porul illarku ivvulagillai' - that world is not for those without benevolence, this is world is not for those without wealth

Comment: Under same page you quoted, there is complete Sanskrit quote and context http://wikifoundryattachments.com/gCuhSyUeS6iLcYxEYkiClw%3D%3D22932 .

Comment: @TheDestroyer You're right, I missed the attachment when I read it earlier. So seems like a subhāṣita.

Answer (score 2):

> Vedamulam Idam braamhyam  Krushimulam Idam dhanyam Bharya Mulam idam
>   Gurham Dhanam mulam idam Jagath

This is the full version. Ref: VydikaVignanam for source and authenticity. Or you are welcome to my home I can show you a BIG book bought by my dad in 1970s.

oh .. I just saw the previous answer that has the full shlokam and explanation too .. But I don't want to delete my reply ;-)

Comment: 'you are welcome to my home I can show you a BIG book' - that's too much trouble, taking a pic and posting it in your answer will do :P

Comment: Where is the previous answer?

Comment: As a non-speaker of Sanskrit, I would love if somebody could give an English translation of the full version? 